# Bulk AD user Attribute Update

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory

I have a csv file with two columns  SamAccount and EmployeeID.  I need some help with doing a bulk change in AD using powershell to add the employee ID to each corresponding user from the csv.

Ive performed import's before but just Get commands. Where do I start?

Answer (score 2):

Youd want to build a loop to loop through all your samaccount names and use [Set-AdUser](http://ss64.com/ps/set-aduser.html) to update all the accounts with the employee ID

EDIT Based on your comment:

sample CSV:

```
samName,empID
user1,123
user2,456
```

Sample Code

```
$SamIDList = import-csv C:\someFile.csv

foreach($id in $SamIDList)
{
$id.samName
$id.empID
}
```

This would output this:

```
user1
123
user2
456
```

Comment: I know how to do that, but what confuses me is how to utilize the second column in correspondence with the first.  So that Row 1 user   id  updates then moves to row 2.

Comment: hopefully those changes make sense and point you in the right direction. So in your set ad user you reference those columns and when you go through each loop it will pull the next line of the csv with the matching samaccountname and employee ID

Comment: it did thanks. I posted what I used. It worked perfect.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code I used

```
    $users = Import-Csv -Path C:\importfile.csv            

    foreach ($user in $users) {            
    Set-ADuser -Identity $($user.sam) -EmployeeID $($user.ID)           
    }
```

CSV:

Sam,ID

Testuser,100